# Angular/ui-router: indent level in source files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lately I became quite concerned about how AngularJS/ui-router applications “grow to the right”. *TL;DR:* how do you reduce the amount of code nesting?

OK, let me try to explain this. Typical Angular/ui-router application has following structure:

- top-level module like `(function(angular){ ... })(angular)` usually wraps entire source file so that all variables stay local and do not leak into global context;
- then you usually go with `module.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) { ... } ])` where you define states;
- state declaration with a controller looks like this (in its minimum verbosity):

  ```
  $stateProvider.state('myState', {
    controller: function() {
      ...  // thus introducing two more indent levels for your code
    }
  });
  ```
- if you choose array syntax for Strict DI and you have a handful of dependencies, you usually end up with a line break, which introduces a continuation indent:

  ```
  $stateProvider.state('myState', {
    controller: ['dependency1', 'dependency2', 'dependency3',
      function(dep1, dep2, dep3) {
        ...  // now there's three indents
      }
    ]
  });
  ```
- finally, if you use named views, you have two more levels:

  ```
  $stateProvider.state('myState', {
    views: {
      myView: {    
        controller: ['dependency1', 'dependency2', 'dependency3',
          function(dep1, dep2, dep3) {
            ...  // wow, five levels!
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
  ```

Eventually, you end up with **7th indent levels** only to begin the application logic code! That's 14 spaces out of conventional 120 symbols per code line (more than 10%). And look at the end of your source file:

```
              };

            }]
        }
      }
    });

  } ]);
})(angular);
```

I was thinking about employing Browserify to allow Node.js-style `requires`, but it only compensates two levels:

```
(function(angular) {

  ...
  module.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('myState', require('./myState'));

  }]);

})(angular)


// myState.js

module.exports = {
  views: {
    myView: {    
      controller: ['dependency1', 'dependency2', 'dependency3',
        function(dep1, dep2, dep3) {
          ...  // still five levels :(
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, we could extract controller itself to reduce two more indents, but it is quite inconvenient, especially if controller is preceded by `resolve`.

Besides, there are another cons with Browserify:

- it adds a bit of metadata overhead in production,
- it needs a watchdog process to allow hot-reloading in development,
- development becomes a bit slower during to constant recompiles; when codebase grows larger it becomes quite an issue.

Now I would love to hear any ideas from you.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide for how you can use `angular.module` to defined controllers and then simply use the controller's name as a string.

Comment: it's how javascript works. Are you writing unit tests? if so - defining controllers separately make testing easier. Another thing is that views is just an js object. you can define it property by property... don't have to define it all at once. But if it will help development - it's a different question.

Comment: @lujcon Nope, I only write end-to-end tests since testing trivial UI logic separately from the end results makes almost no sense. A big picture behind my question is that I am trying to achieve _beautiful_ structure, where every component has its place, is "transparent" and "accessible" to the developer, friendly to development and production phases (both are almost equally important) and so on.